# How to assign my wireless keyboard as stdin to a python3 script?

Tags: python-3.x, bluetooth, keyboard, stdin, systemd

I have a wireless keyboard connected to a raspberry pi. Now when I start the Pi the keyboard will „hang“ at the login prompt.

The whole setup is headless and I want to assign the keyboard to a python3 script that is running at the same time through SystemD.

The stream is located at:

```
/dev/input/event0
```

As I said it’s fine if the script completely hijacks the keyboard.

### Update

Another option for me would to simply start into my program at boot rather than the default shell prompt. This would ensure that it has the „focus“ of the keyboard.

Comment: How dou you know it is connected, if your raspi hangs at login shell ?

Comment: Because I can enter text at the login shell. Also I can detect keystrokes using the evdev python module

Comment: please post the complete output of `lsusb --verbose` (when the keyboard is connected)

Comment: It's a wireless keyboard so it does not show up using `lsusb`. The only thing that's currently shown is the hub: `Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found a very simple answer : since you have python-evdev already installed on your system, you can use this module in your python3 program to achieve just what you want. Add `import evdev` to the top of your python3 program. Then, you have to create a `evdev.device.InputDevice` first thing in your program with `"/dev/input/event0"` as parameter (the path of your keyboard). Then, call `evdev.device.InputDevice.grab`, and it should be done ! I do not have the code of your program, but i wrote a little sample program:

```py
import evdev, sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    dev = evdev.device.InputDevice("/dev/input/event0")
    try:
        dev.grab()
    except IOError:
        print("error : /dev/input/event0 has already been grabbed")
        sys.exit(1)
    else:
        count = 0
        while count <= 100:
            instr = input("Enter something : ")
            print("You entered : " + instr)
            count += 1
        try:
            dev.ungrab() # important : free your keyboard when the script exits !
        except IOError:
            print("error : /dev/input/event0 has already been released")
            sys.exit(1)
```

EDIT:

I found out that the above sample program will not automatically capture the keystrokes and deliver you the text. You have to do that manually, an example can be found [here](https://python-evdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#reading-events)

Comment: hy there I did try your script but when I enter text nothing happens.

Comment: @Besi thats weird ... Are you sure the keyboard is located at /dev/input/event0 ?

Comment: @Besi yould you maybe post your original python3 script ?

Comment: @Besi ok my keyboard is located at /dev/input/event4, and when i change the paths in my sample script to that, the keyboard is grabbed, but the python script somehow doesnt get the text ... I will see if i can work this out

Comment: @Besi I DID work it out : once you have grabbed the keyboard, you have to receive the keystrokes as events and manually convert the events to text. [Here is an example.](https://python-evdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#reading-events)

Comment: Could you incorporate the information from your comment into the answer, then I will accept it, although it is not exactly what I was looking for and I'll have to mimic a keyboard (including implementing backspace and shift etc.) but it is a valid workaround.

Comment: @Besi ok i will do it later this evening !

Comment: @Besi i edited my post to include the example